# Drupal : How to remove the <p> and <br> tag from content when using syntaxhighlighter

Tags: drupal-7

**Used Version 7.14**

I am using [syntaxhighlighter](http://drupal.org/project/syntaxhighlighter)  for my website. But when I insert some code samples it always producing output with more

and 
 also content in single line as well .

I am done just copy paste the code from zend studio editor inside the syntaxhighlighter tag

I've searched over many forums and druapl site itself, but nothing works for me. Please advise me on this

See the picture below  for more

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your input formats
/admin/config/content/formats
and CKEditor Clenup and output settings 
/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit